# JavaMail through Exchange server with SSO Authentication

Tags: java, single-sign-on, jakarta-mail, exchange-server, ntlm

I've seen several posts that offer a solution to something very similar to my situation but for whatever reason it does not work for me.

For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630160/javamail-ntlm-authentication-using-credentials-of-current-user) it's presented as a working sample illustrating OP's related problem and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19793096/2055998) as an actual answer.

I need to send e-mail as myself from my Exchange account via SMTP using SSO UserID and Password.  This all happens in a restricted corporate environment.

From what I understand from the debug info I'm successfully connecting to an SMTP server and then fail user authentication with `530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated`.  `NTLM` authentication itself seems to be enabled.

DEBUG:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.4
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "server.bank.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 server1.corp.bank.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 24 Aug 2015 17:15:24 -0400
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "server.bank.com", port: 25

EHLO server2.corp.bank.com
250-server1.corp.bank.com Hello [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
250-SIZE
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS
250-AUTH NTLM LOGIN
250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-XEXCH50
250-XRDST
250 XSHADOW
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-ANONYMOUSTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "NTLM LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-EXPS", arg "GSSAPI NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XEXCH50", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XRDST", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XSHADOW", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<first.last@bank.com>
530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated
DEBUG SMTP: got response code 530, with response: 530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated
```

Essential part of my code:

```
static void sendEmail(){

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    // props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
    // props.setProperty("mail.debug.auth", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "NTLM");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth.ntlm.domain", user_sso_domain);

    // Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(user_sso_id, user_sso_password);
                }
            });
    session.setDebug(true);

    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(email_from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(email_to));
        message.setSubject("Test Message");
        message.setText("This is my test message");
        Transport.send(message);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I would appreciate your suggestions for further troubleshooting.

**EDIT**

Working code after implementing the fix and better practices from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32193504/2055998):

```
private static void sendEmail(){

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    // props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
    // props.setProperty("mail.debug.auth", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "NTLM");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth.ntlm.domain", user_sso_domain);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    session.setDebug(true);

    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(email_from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(email_to));
        message.setSubject("Test Message");
        message.setText("This is my test message");
        Transport.send(message, user_sso_id, user_sso_password);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set "mail.smtp.auth" to "true".

Or, better yet, fix these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) and make your program much simpler.